# When i need to persist dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am curious to know when i need to persist my dataframe in spark and when not. Cases:-

1. If i need data from file ( Do i need to persist it? if i apply repetitive count  like:-

```
val df=spark.read.json("file://root/Download/file.json")
df.count
df.count
```

Do i need to persist df?? because according to me it should store df in memory after first count and use same df in second count. Record in file is 4 , Because when i practically check it , it read file again and again, So why spark doesn't store it in memory

2. Second question is in spark read is an action or transformation?

Comment: Why not store the count to a variable?

Comment: I used count for sake of example. What i mean is that I am performing multiple action on same dataframe and no transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataFrames by design are immutable, so every transformation done on them would create a new data frame altogether. A spark pipeline generally involves multiple transformations leading to multiple data frames being created. If spark stores all of these data frames, the memory requirement would be huge. So spark leaves the responsibility of persisting data frames to the user. Whichever data frame you are planning on re using, you can persist them and later unpersist them when done.

I don't think we can define spark read as an action or a transformation. Action/Transformation is applied over a data frame. To identify the difference, you should remember that the transformation operation will return a new dataframe while action will return some value/s.